# Trying to restore a db2 database but stops at roll-forward with error 'SQL1265N'

Tags: backup, restore, log, db2-9.7

I'm trying to restore a backup that is older than the current database.

The restore went ok, but the roll forward didn't giving the following error:

> SQL1265N The archive log file ".LOG" is not associated with the
>   current log sequence for database "" on node "0".

I tried to roll forward to an earlier point in time, but it is required to restore to the end of the logs.

The backup is from another server but it's actually a duplicate (so name etc. are the same.)

What steps can I take to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to remove the existing log files from the new server (or better move them somewhere else) and copy the log files from the old server to the new server. It is not possible to rollforward the backup from the old server with the transaction logs from the new server.

Be carefully when you remove the transaction logs from the new server. You wan't be able to rollforward a previous backup taken on the new server.

Comment: Wow, thanks for answering, but I don't work for this company anymore and so cannot confirm if this solution works or not.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize when you asked this. :-)

Comment: yeah ... haha... almost 6 years ago